# Buttons to Update Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 models: Restaurant/User/Reservation.

Reservation belongs_to both other models (the other two are has_many, through:).

I need a user to be able to make a reservation @ a restaurant. I wanted to make a button to do it:

```
    <h1>Restaurants#index</h1>
<% @all.each do |x| %>
    <%= link_to x.name %><br>
    <%= x.image %><br>
    <%= x.current_capacity %>/<%= x.capacity %>
    <p><%= submit_tag "Reserve?" %></p>
<% end %>
```

How can I design this functionality? I was originally thinking to have a column under Restaurants for "capacity" and "current_capacity" and worry about using time later. How can I get this button to set an instance of Restaurant to update its current_capacity?

Comment: @all are restaurants? can you upload the controller?

Comment: It just has the code 
def index
     @all = Restaurant.all
end